# Why is Try the default implicit Applicative instance in cats

Tags: scala, traits, implicit, scala-cats

Playing around with cats, I have noticed a certain behavior which I cannot quite explain:

```
import cats.implicits._
...
def wrapA[A, F[_]](v: A)(implicit F: Applicative[F]): F[A] = F.pure(v)
```

not a particularly useful method, just playing around.

while fully parametrizing the method or passing the required instance explicitly works fine:

```
val o: Option[Int] = wrapA[Int, Option](1)
val o: Option[Int] = wrapA(1)(catsStdInstancesForOption)
```

this does not typecheck:

```
val o: Option[Int] = wrapA(1) // found scala.util.Try[Int], required Option[Int]
```

Ok, `TryInstances` are resolved before the `OptionInstances`

```
trait AllInstances
  ...
  with    OptionInstances
  ...
  with    TryInstances
  with    TupleInstances
  ...
```

But then why is not `Tuple2` expected instead of `Try`? The `TupleInstances` are resolved before `TryInstances` and define an `Applicative` instance. Is it arity? Is there a particular reason for the order of the instances? And while I see that the value type does not influence implicit resolution, why doesnt it?

Cats 0.9.0, Scala 2.12.1

Thank you.

**EDIT** There seems to be no `Applicative` instance for `Tuple2` after all and thus no `pure`, so this part of the question seems to be sorted out.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but this is a fun question, and seems [weirder than I thought at first](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/ab14e58b94683943961f5043291c4fbd) it would be.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting, the ambiguity in the last example is a bit unexpected :) Thanks Travis.